# Issue with extern "C++" in Apple Clang

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, clang++

Is there any difference between these two:

```
//MyFile.cpp
#include "myheader.hpp"       //works fine in Apple Clang13 as well as 14


//MyFile.cpp
extern "C"
{
    extern "C++"
    {
        #include "myheader.hpp".      //compilation error in Apple Clang13
    }
}
```

In the later case, I am getting compilation errors due to namespaces while I didn't get any such error in the former case. Also the issue occurs only in `Apple Clang13` and not in `Apple Clang14`.
`myheader.hpp`  further includes a lot of other headers including `boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp`.

```
// In file boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp

:
:
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os,
      const dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& b)
{

    using namespace std;

    const ios_base::iostate ok = ios_base::goodbit;  
    //error - undeclared identifier ios_base in apple clang13, did you mean std::ios_base
    //works fine in clang13 after changing it to std::ios_base::iostate
   //works fine in apple clang14 with no change

 :
 :
 :
}
```

My actual requirement is that I have a client code which includes my header in `extern "C"` block. I can't change the client's code. In my header, I want to use `C++` code. So, code is something like this:

```
//public_header.h   //client's header,   //can't change
extern "C"{
myheader.hpp
}


//myheader.hpp    // This I can change
#ifdef my_flag       //only defined for c++ targets
extern "C++"{  
    #include "boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp" //c++ code
}
}
```

So, basically I want `C++` linkage inside an `extern "C"` block. Can there be alternate ways of doing this without using extern "C++" block? My aim is to use boost headers(templates) inside extern "C" block.

Note - Issue is reproducible with mentioned boost header in Clang13.

Comment: Why have nested `extern "C++"` at all? This feature doesn't seem have a good reason to be nested. You should have just separate block for C code and separate block fo C++ code (in fact I do not see reason to have `extern "C++"`).

Comment: @MarekR, Any other alternative? My aim is to use boost headers(templates) inside extern "C" block. I can't remove extern "C" block as it is in client's code.

Comment: just surround `C`-stuff with `extern "C"` and everything else put outside of this block. Do not make things over complicated.

Comment: I could do that but I can't change client header which includes extern "C" block. Is there a way to detect if code is inside extern "C" block So that I can end extern "C" block in the beginning of my header and hence put everything else outside the extern "C" block? I think no.

Comment: So there is not problem!  Client header which includes `extern "C"` block? Cool in your header just do regular includes no `extern "C"` or `extern "C++"`.

Comment: If I use regular includes, it throws error at client's code. Error- Template must have C++ linkage. Client is including header in extern "C" block hence the whole header(including templates) goes in extern "C" block

Comment: So looks like you are trying to use C++ futures in C code. Including C++ header into c source code. This is impossible. You have to hide C++ features from C compiler. Based on last comment clearly your question suffers form [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253232/discussion-between-vivek-mangal-and-marek-r).

Answer (score -1):

Based on comments looks like `Vivek Mangal` do not understand why extern "C" is needed.

## C vs C++ important difference

In C++ you have possibility to do function overload. C do not have this feature. So if you have C library functions are exposed under they names (with underscore prefix - not important)

Now since C++ has function overload, this mean that under same name there can be multiple functions. Since first C++ compiler was generating C code result code had to provide unique function names for those overloads. So name mangling was introduced. Basically compiler generates unique name for each function overload which contains information about function arguments or a namespace.

## Problem of name mangling

Now when you try use C code in C++ code compiler must know which functions has been compiled as "C" and which functions are C++, so during liking it could find "C" functions by they regular names and C++ functions by they mangled names.

That is why `extern "C"` comes in - it basically turns of name mangling. If `extern "C"` is not used for C-function in C++ code you will see linking issue that linker can't find definition of a function with mangled name (since function is available under regular name).

## Well behaving C library

Now developer of C library which wishes his library is usable in C++ code should deliver headers which look like this:

```cpp
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD
#define HEADER_GUARD
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus

// C function declarations:
....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __cplusplus

#endif // HEADER_GUARD
```

This way when header is compiled in C-mode, `extern "C" {` is ingnored using preprocesor. And when header is compiled in C++-mode all functions are surrounded by `extern "C" {` and compiler will no use name mangling for those headers.

This way C++ developer do not have to do anything special to use C-API.

Looks like you are in this scenario.

## Regular C library in C++ code

Quite often author of C-library do not think about C++ then user of such library is responsible to make sure that name mangling is disabled. In such case, you need just do something like this:

```cpp
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD
#define HEADER_GUARD

#include <vector>
extern "C" {
#include <some-C-library/header1.h>
#include <some-C-library/header2.h>
}

class FOO {
};

#endif // HEADER_GUARD
```

`#ifdef __cplusplus` here is not needed since this header uses C++ feature, which can't be used in `C` so there is not point to try make it work in `C`-mode.

## Summary

Based on that it should be clear for you you do not need use `extern "C++"` at all!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed insight. What I was trying to do is using C++ features inside <some-C-library/header1.h>. So I wrapped them inside extern "C++" block. It worked in clang14. I am sure that those features will not be reachable to C code because I will wrap them inside a flag which only my C++ target will define. May be I should think about alternate approaches. Thanks again.